# Can I mock a method with specified parameters by using `mock` in python?

Tags: python, mocking, python-mock, python-unittest

I know if I do this:

```
import mock
my.factory = mock.MagicMock()
```

then all the things my.factory are mocked, but in fatory there is a method: `create_fruit(self, type)` I want if I pass-in `'apple'` then return a mocked `'apple'` object, if I pass-in a `'banana'`then return me a `'banana'` object.

Can this be implemented by `mock` module? I cannot find it clearly in doc:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/mock

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can. But you will have to define a function for it.

```
from mock import Mock

def mock_create_fruit(fruit):
    if fruit not in ('apple', 'banana'):
        raise AssertionError('create_fruit not called with an allowed type, was %s' % (fruit,)
    return type(fruit, (object,), {})()

my.factory.create_fruit = Mock(side_effect=mock_create_fruit)
```

The last line of our mock_create_fruit function is creating a class on the fly, creating an instance of it, and then returning it to the caller.